# merge data into single one for an email : Python

Tags: python, email, merge

I would like to merge data so I can send only one email

```
for body in result:
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg.set_content(body)
        msg['From'] = email_address
        msg['To'] = recipient_address
        msg['Subject'] = subject_desc
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login("youremail@gmail.com", password)
        print("login success")
        server.send_message(msg)
        print("This message has been sent")
        server.quit()
```

This code actually sends me a dozen of single email with data I got from `result` as it's in a loop but I would like to get one single email for those dozen of data.
I tried something like this :

```
def email(body):
    data = []
    for body in result:
        data.append(body)
    return data
```

but it's still sending dozen of email instead of one how could I do it ?

Thank you by advance :)

Comment: if you have list with many strings then create one string `text = "\n".join(result)` and send `text` without `for`-loop.

Comment: you second code simply move data from one list to another - so it is useless. You should  get the same with `data = result` or `data = result.copy()`

Comment: Yes absolutely, it what I needed, thank you really much ^^ I was thinking about a loop with `for` cause it's actually a tracking script i'm writting and I want to execute it again when result is "empty" a `while True:` is more appropriate

thank for your advice again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have list with many strings then create one string

```
body = "\n".join(result)
```

and send without `for`-loop.

```
msg = EmailMessage()

body = "\n".join(result)
#body = "\n---\n".join(result) # to separate result with line `---`

msg.set_content(body)

msg['From'] = email_address
msg['To'] = recipient_address
msg['Subject'] = subject_desc
```

---

If you have list with filenames then you can use `for`-loop but with different indentation.

It is example for sending only images. For other type of files it would need different `maintype`,`subtype`

```
filenames = ['images/lenna.jpg', 'images/cats.jpg']

# ... 

msg = EmailMessage()

for name in filenames:
    msg.add_attachment(open(name, 'rb').read(), filename=name, maintype='text', subtype='jpg')

msg['From'] = email_address
msg['To'] = recipient_address
msg['Subject'] = subject_desc
```

Or you can use other module to guess type

```
import mimetypes

# ... code ...

for name in filenames:
    ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(name)
    print(name, ctype, encoding)
    maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/')
    msg.add_attachment(open(name, 'rb').read(), filename=name, maintype=maintype, subtype=subtype)
```

---

Of course you can also use `set_content()` and `add_attachment()` in the same mail.
It can be used to send HTML with images - but I skip this example.

Comment: Thank for your detailed explanation :) I'll pratice on it to understand all the proccess